LightGBM with Multi-Output Regression and Custom Loss Function
Can I use LightGBM with Multi-Output Regression and also a custom Loss Function?
Problem is I have to use LightGBM.
I know that i can use MultiOutputRegression by sklearn to wrap LightGBM but this doesnt allow me to define a custom loss function, as I could do it with Keras.

Is there any particular reason you want one big model for multiple outputs? If you just have multiple outputs you want to predict, why not just build a separate model for each output. This also maximises the use of your data if you have any NaN values.

I have interdependencies between the predictions.
The task is to predict demands in a setting where we have customer substitution. So if the demand of one product is not satisfied by the stock (demand prediction) it can be substituted to other products with certain probabilities. And the task is also to include this into the loss function to optimize the problem within the demand forecasting.

This is quite an uninformed response. There are plenty of reasons not to disregard existing interdependencies.
